# Three digit lottery program in java

Tags: java

I just started an intro to java programming class so I do not know much. I am having trouble obtaining the middle digit of the lottery variable. I used `int lotteryDigit1 = lottery / 100;` and `int lotteryDigit2 = lottery % 100;` to get the first and last number but I am having trouble getting the middle digit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lottery {`enter code here`
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //generate random lottery numbers 
        int lottery = (int)(Math.random() * 100);



        //ask user to enter a 3 digit guess
        Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your lottery pick. Three Digits Only");
        int guess = numbers.nextInt();

        //digits for lottery
        int lotteryDigit1 = lottery / 100;

        int lotteryDigit2 = lottery % 100;


        //digits for guess
        int guessdigit1 = guess / 100; 
        int guessdigit2 = guess % 100;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what output you get and what output you expect?

Comment: I am getting the first and last digits of my int lottery = (int)(Math.random() * 100); but the middle digit isn't outputting. The exercise says to use / and % to get the first and last digit but I am unsure of how to get the middle digit.

Comment: @SamXeox Are the below answers not of any use?

Comment: @Scary Wombat Unfortunately not because I forgot to mention that it says that I can only use / and % to get the middle digit so I am a little lost because I see no way to get the middle digit of a random number with only using / and %. Am i missing something?

Comment: Huh, I am only using `%` and `/` - what's wrong?

Comment: int lottery hast to be a random three-digit number though and then I need to output the random three-digit number.

Comment: BTW, `int lottery = (int)(Math.random() * 100);` will **never** five you are number greater than 100, try 1000

Comment: Hey, that worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
int lottery = 123;
System.out.println(lottery);
System.out.println(lottery % 10);
System.out.println(lottery % 100 / 10);
System.out.println(lottery / 100);
```

**output**

```
123
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write small util function to return digit at given position:

```
public static int digitAt(int input, int position){     
    int i =(int) (input % (Math.pow(10, position)));
    int result = (int) (i / Math.pow(10, position - 1));
    return result;
}
```